# Decrypt data on client machine

Tags: encryption, server, client

If I want to encrypt data on a server, and send it to a client program which I have implemented and sent to the customer, is there anyway that I can store the decryption key and algorithm in the client program, without risking that reverse engineering my client program will enable the user to decrypt all the data I send.
That is, I want my client program to control what it decrypts and what not.

Thanks
Jeeji

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hard-code the algorithm with no risk. The security must be based in the secrecy of the key, not of the algorithm.

To secretly store the decryption key, you can use a keystore.

I don't know which language you are using, but Java includes its own keystore, and for C you get a keystore through NSS. To open these keystores you will need a password that the user can type in when the client application starts up.

If your client runs on linux and gnome, then you could also use Gnome's keyring, in which case the user will not need to type the password to open the keyring (the log-in password is also used to open the keyring).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I imagined it was something like that. It will be a .Net solution and I assume that .Net has a something similar to keystore. But I am not sure if it is what I want! I actually would prefer no interaction by the user on the client to perform the decryption. So is it possible that my application can by itself decrypt without any interaction?

Comment: ... and if no, and I choose to use your above described method, how do I go about distributing the client application to the customers. Does each client have to get a unique password for the keystore, and is the descryption key and the keystore part of the distibution package of the client?

Comment: Key distribution is a whole subject in itself. You can manually distribute the key (carry it in a pen drive and add it to the keystore when you install the application).
Or you can create the keystore during the automatic installation and download the key using [Diffie-Hellman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange).
In both cases the user will have to provide the keystore password to open it.
I wonder if your problem could not be solver using SSL... Despite all the recent problems, TLS 1.2 is still considered secure.

Comment: Thanks again. The thing is that I do not want any further communication between server and client, so basically I want encrypted data to lie on the client, and it should be the client and only the client that choose what and when to decrypt. A thought comes to mind: Is it possible to use some .Net signing of the client assembly, to ensure that it is the only assembly that may retrieve the decryption key, and use it to decrypt? Thanks again